# How to post via email on Sina Weibo

Tags: weibo

Is it possible to post to Sina [Weibo.com](http://www.weibo.com/) (*Chinese version of Twitter*) via email?

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I have researched. My Chinese colleague also searched on the Chinese web support sites and couldn't find any help.